# Page redirect is not work properly in php

Tags: php

I have faced page redirect issue in PHP , I know there are many questions regarding on it has asked in stack overflow but i didn't get any solution from it.

Following is my code of simple page redirect.

```
<?php

if( empty($_SESSION['JNA_customer_id']) && $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != '/app'.$demo.'/index.php' && $pos === false ){
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['redirect'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    


    header('location:http://'.get_base_url().'index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

I have also tried like `header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." ");` but still not redirect page it's showing .

Also tried `javascript` redirection

> `The page isn’t redirecting properly`

Someone know better solution for this the please help me on this stuck.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your browser saying: _The page isn’t redirecting properly_? if so, make sure you are not stuck in a redirection loop.

Comment: Yes , i am getting The page isn’t redirecting properly error.

Comment: Use F12 developer tools to watch the network traffic. You will probably see page A redirecting to page B and then back to page A etc.

Comment: Yes i see there are 13-14 times redirect same page with showing status 302 .